# What is a natural way to talk about "other books" in a heading?

Tags: vocabulaire

I have headings that appear on the back of a book.

The headings are:

- Other Puzzle Books
- Other Number Search Books.
- Other Maze Books.
- Other Sudoku Books.

(Under the headings are photos of the other books).

What would be a natural way of conveying this?

---

### Possible options

**1. Autres**

This would be a direction translation of the English, "other".

Example:

```
Autres livres de casse-tête
Autres livres de Nombres mêlés.
Autres livres de Labyrinthe.
Autres livres de Sudoku.
```

However, I am not sure if it's natural sounding.

**2. Dans la même collection de**

```
Dans la même collection de de casse-tête
Dans la même collection de Nombres mêlés.
Dans la même collection de Labyrinthe.
Dans la même collection de Sudoku.
```

I have seen this on the back of children's books. However, I am not sure if it's something that is exclusively for children books and might sound odd for an adult audience?

**3. Nos livres**

This is the equivalent of "our books":

```
Nos livres casse-tête
Nos livres Nombres mêlés.
Nos livres Labyrinthe.
Nos livres Sudoku.
```

I am not sure if the use of "our" is too personal. But also, the heading appears in the back of an existing book. So, in English at least, "Other" would fit better. I am not sure if it's the same in French.

**4. Dans notre collection**

This is the equivalent of "in our collection"

```
Dans notre collection casse-tête
Dans notre collection Nombres mêlés.
Dans notre collection Labyrinthe.
Dans notre collection Sudoku.
```

But again, I am not sure if it is too personal.

(N.B. Please do not limit answers just to these possible options if something more natural exists).

Comment: "Dans notre collection" sounds definitely familiar (I mean, something you would see in real life).

Comment: “Dans notre collection “ ==> “du même éditeur” ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All are correct bar some possible ajustments. It is probably better to use the plural for "casse-tête" (casse-têtes) and for "labyrinthe" (labyrinthes). "Sudoku" can be considered to be both a countable noun and an uncountable one so that either the uncountable form (sudoku) or the plural countable form is proper.

The word "recueil" instead of "livre" can be used; it is used in particular for "sudoku" ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=fecueil+de+sudoku)); the term "carnet" is also found ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=carnet+de+sudoku)).

The upper-case for "nombres-mêlés", "labyrinthe" and "sudoku" are only needed if the words have been chosen by the publisher as the name of a collection.

1/

- Autres livres de casse-tête**s**
- Autres livres de nombres mêlés.
- Autres livres de labyrinthe**s**.
- Autres livres de sudoku(**s**).

It should be remarked that "[livres des labyrinthes](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=livres+de+labyrinthes)" is used a lot (despite the not very logical "des").

2/

- Dans la même collection de livres de casse-tête**s**
- Dans la même collection de livres de nombres mêlés.
- Dans la même collection de livres de  labyrinthe**s**.
- Dans la même collection de livres de  sudoku(**s**).

Another option consists in suppressing the whole prepositional phrase that precedes the term and using a plural, or even in suppressing the term as well.

- Dans la même collection

3/

- Nos livres de (jeux de) casse-tête**s**
- Nos livres de (jeux de) nombres mêlés.
- Nos livres de Labyrinthe**s**.
- Nos livres de (jeu(x) de) sudoku.

4/

- Dans notre collection casse-tête**s**
- Dans notre collection nombres mêlés.
- Dans notre collection labyrinthe**s**.
- Dans notre collection sudoku(**s**).